# How can I remove this duplicate code when using Boost serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

In my application I have a number of classes that I want to be able to serialize. So each class whose instances need to be serializeable has the following:

```
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
       // ar & (all data members) 
    }
```

To serialize the object I then need to use this code from outside the class:

```
    ObjectToSerialize obj;
    stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << obj;
```

This second block of code is annoying me because I have to use it everytime I want to serialize an object. Is there any way I can move this code to one location and call it when I need to serialize an object?

I could have an object with this method:

```
    string serializeObject(Serializable obj)
```

But the problem with this is that there is no way to determine which objects are 'serializable' as there is no supertype that a class must implement when adding boost seriization functionality.

So how can I put this code in one place and only allow objects that are serializable to be passed to the method?

Comment: are you are looking for compile-time checking to ensure that the object is serializable?

Comment: @David Hope I am, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a template function that takes a object that has a serialize function.

```
template <typename T> std::string serializeObject(T obj) {
    stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << obj;
    //...
}


std:String str = serializeObject(ObjectToSerialize);
```

Comment: What would happen if I passed in an object that didn't have boost serialization functionality?

Comment: @Frammo That's the amazing part about templates they will throw a compile time error if the object didn't have boost serialization functionality.

Comment: @Andre I will code it up an if it works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I got no errors when trying to serialize an object that doesn't have anything to do with boost::serialization. Any ideas why. Is there some sort of default serialization functionality that is used when the coder doesn't provide any?

Comment: @Frammo you'll need a way to invoke serialize in the method so the compiler know to check for that function.

Comment: I tried it with something totally different and I did get a compile error Woooo. I'm new to C++ so didn't really understand templates. But they are amazing!! Thank you.

Comment: @Frammo templates are powerful. The reason why function works with non serialize object is because `boost::archive::text_oarchive` and `oa << obj;` function with non-serialize objects. I'll see about forcing the method to check for the function serialize.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24914/discussion-between-frammo-and-andre)

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: you don't want and need a base class for those objects. So instead of dynamic polymorphism use *static* polymorphism:

```
template <class Serializable>
std::string serializeObject(Serializable& s)
{
  stringstream ss;
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
  oa << obj;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Now if you pass something to the function that is not serializable, you get a compiler error. To make the error more readable, you could try to use some SFINAE based techniques like `std::enable_if`

Comment: I didn't know that templates had the same robustness as dynamic polymorphism. So I've learned something :P